# Average multiple vectors of points of different lengths in python

Tags: python, interpolation

I have a list of trajectories for different trials that themselves are a list of points...

```
trajectories = [[(x,y),(x,y), ...], [(x,y), ...], ...]
```

the number of points vary from trial to trial.

The final goal is to plot average trajectory +/- SEM (Standard Error of Mean) across trials.

As far as I can understand I should get the longest trajectory and for each of the remaining trajectories add 'resolution' to the other vectors so they are the same length, so something like this:

```
#find the maximum length
max_len = len(trajectories[0])
longest = []
for t in trajectories:
    if len(t) > max_len:
        max_len = len(t)
        longest = t
# now transform the other vectors I assume using the longest vector or the length of this vector 
newTrajectories = []
for i,t in enumerate(trajectories):
    newTrajectories[i] = resample(t, longest or max_len, or something similar!!)
```

Is there a function that given a vec of tuples (x,y) of len X and another of len Y where X>Y adds points (x,y) to the Y vec in the right places like using the average of previous and following point or the median?

**Edit**: 
The simplest example I can think of is using 2 vectors of trajectories:

```
vec_one = [(2,4),(3,5),(1,6)]
vec_two = [(2,4), (1,6)]
```

Both of them start from x=2, y=4 and end up in x=1, y=6
vec_one however is longer (it took more time).
I figure that to be able to average across trajectories, vec_two needs to be longer so I would need to extrapolate, in some way, the values of the x,y position that is missing.

I've been looking at splprep, splrep and splev of the scypi.interpolate module, but I'm afraid I don't quite understand them yet.

**Edit2**: Effectively I'm trying to abstract out time from an (x,y) time series. So the problem becomes where to introduce new values and by which criteria I select a 'site' for inserting values, the way I extrapolate the values seems now less impotant...

Comment: What do you mean by "average trajectory +/- sem across trials". Did you mean "average trajectory +/- sum"?? If you need average trajectory, what do you mean by +/-?

Comment: sorry SEM = Standard Error of Mean :)

Comment: And how about the trajectory co-ordinates.. are the x,y co-ordinates integer values? And for a given trajectory, do you have the trajectory co-ordinates for each x<range...

Comment: X and y are floats, they are the center of mass of a distribution of pixels that I'm tracking in a 640x480,30fps video. I don't understand what you mean by "trajectory coordinates of x<range..."

Comment: Basically I assume that you would require to find the average trajectory prior to computer the SEM. Is it correct? And for finding the average trajectory, you should require to average your y co-ordinate for every x value. The range of x should be [0, max_range]. And in order to be able to find the average of y at every x, you would require to have trajectory co-ordinates for all x which is less than the range. I hope that makes me more clear. Let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: I think so. the SEM is not the problem its just the std/sqrt(N) where N is the number of samples. My problem is calculating an average trajectory for vectors of different lengths. I'll edit the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no takers, here is a solution I find works ok.

I had to change the format of the data to solve this.
So instead of having a list of trials with variable number of (x, y) points:
[[(x, y), (x, y), ...], [(x, y), (...), ...]]

I now have 3 numpy.arrays:

**sx** = array([ 23,  34,  42, ...,  56,  56,  63])

**sy** = array([ 78,  94,  20, ...,  44,  38,  34])

**st** = array([1, 1, 1, ..., 293, 293, 293])

All vectors are the same length as they are essentially part of a table, where **sx** is the column with all the x positions, **sy** is all the y positions and **st** is the trial number (or the list ID of the x and y positions). **st** is basically a bunch of repeated numbers [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,...]

(I'm actually using HDF5/pytables to store my data and its a direct read from the table that contains the tracking data)

This solution uses interp1d

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
```

as well as numpy of course

```
import numpy as np
```

I admit its a hacked solution and not really fast but it works :) On the other hand re-reading my own question made me think it was not a very clear exposition of my problem... sorry for that. Anyway here is the solution.

The following func receives the 3 vecs I described above, a **trialList**, which is a list of trials to collapse across and a **kind**, which is the type of collapsing you want to do, can be mean or median for now. It will return the collapsed trajectory i.e. the x and y positions of the average or the median of the trialList

```
def collapseTrajectories(sx, sy, st, trialList, kind='median'):
    # find the longest trial to use as template
    l = 0
    tr = []
    for t in trialList:
        if len(st[st==t]) > l:
            l = len(st[st==t])
            tr = t

    # Make all vectors the same length by interpolating the values
    xnew = np.linspace(0, 640, l)
    ynew = np.linspace(0, 480, l)
    sx_new = []
    sy_new = []

    for t in trialList:
        if len(st[st==t]) > 3:
            X = sx[st==t]
            Y = sy[st==t]
            x = np.linspace(0,640, len(X))
            y = np.linspace(0,480,len(Y))
            fx = interp1d(x, X, kind='cubic')
            fy = interp1d(y, Y, kind='cubic')
            sx_new.append(fx(xnew))
            sy_new.append(fy(ynew))

    # Collapse using the appropriate kind
    if kind == 'median':
        out_x = np.median(sx_new, axis=0)
        out_y = np.median(sy_new, axis=0)
    elif kind=='mean':
        out_x = np.mean(sx_new, axis=0)
        out_y = np.mean(sy_new, axis=0)

    return out_x, out_y
```

Comment: What would be the way for expanding it to the 3D interpolation? i.e. I have (x,y,z) that I need to interpolate?